# I burned a DVD-R, but after it finished, some files in the DVD cannot be opened. Why?

Tags: dvd-burning

I burned a DVD-R by using Nero BurnLite 10. When the burning process finished, I receive some notification messages about files that cannot be opened. I tried to open them myself and they can't be opened just like the notification said. The original files can be opened without any problem though. What's wrong with this?

Many thanks in advance,

Haris

Comment: This should be in the Super User forum.

Comment: @Ryan: Read: Super User is not a forum. It, however, is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

Did it specify any reasons why the error happened? Sometimes long file names (especially html pages which are named horribly) are the cause of the same. If so rename those files with shorter names and re-burn your matter. There was a limit if I remember clearly of 126 characters but i'm not sure i need to check on this.

Another reason could also be that your burner could be the cause of the trouble, can you burn another DVD without the matter that was giving errors or completely different matter and check if you face the same problem.

Also was your media clean as in was the surface that matter gets burned on to scratched or damaged in anyway.

There could be several reasons so more inputs from you would help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's very quite possible that your files were corrupted as they were written. This happens when the drive skips a beat when going too fast or similar. Try again using either the "verify disc" option enabled or with a burner that supports verifying discs.